# ArcGIS Online Feature Service Exporting Polygons with Topology Errors

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, topology, feature-service

I uploaded a file geodatabase containing towns for all of New England to ArcGIS Online and created a feature service. I ran a topology check in QGIS beforehand and detected no errors. After exporting the same data from ArcGIS Online to a new file geodatabase, I ran the topology check on the new file geodatabase and have thousands of gap errors. Does anyone know why ArcGIS Online isn't handling the data correctly or a workaround?